# Understanding Printing, Postcript file, pdf etc

Tags: pdf, printing, cups, postscript

I have 3 questions.

1. Has .pdf files replaced PostScript for printing?
2. In a normal printing environment, is PostScripts always used to print anything?
3. How does printing actually work in terms of a normal office scenario? (high level overview)

Happy to change my question if it's too open-ended or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to answer your question with an example from my current workplace.

1. Yes. `.pdf` is used instead of `postscript`
2. I don't know what is considered a "normal" printing environment, but I very rarely encounter anybody (except perhaps professional graphic designers) who prints from `postscript`
3. Again, "normal" is hard to define. But we have a setup with a central printer (from HP) that all clients are connected to via ethernet. Some client machines also have their own (smaller) printers, so they don't have to walk over the office just to print a single page.

Answer (score 0):

To the third part of your question:
An office setup could also get achieved with [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/)- A Printing Server running on a Linux Distro on an external device. With cups you could also achieve something like "round robin printing" with multiple printers